# How do I place SSL on a localhost using xampp?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

I have created an SSL certificate, and imported it.

My Apache is working, but my localhost website is not showing https://.  The site is up and running but only as http://.

I followed the steps shown here:
http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords

I am wondering if my problem is "One thing to keep in mind with this redirection is that if you have virtual hosts, you need to place the redirection code (with the RewriteCond and RewriteRule) inside of your virtual host declarations, otherwise the redirection won’t work"?  Not sure what it is or how to do it.

This video is the same as above. I followed it and debugged the code, which is why my Apache is running.  For me the issue was with the Code, not Ports being blocked as many other people had problems with, especially because of Skype, etc.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQZ8wzV9VU8

Hopefully, this makes sense, if you have any questions I'll do my best to answer them.  Any advice, tips or links would be useful.  Thank you.

---

I haven't found away how to correct the "match," if this is the problem.  Did I enter something incorrectly when creating the SSL certificate?.  Error Log is as follows:

> [Fri May 19 16:19:14.955930 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6812:tid 252]
>   AH01909: localhost:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID
>   which matches the server name
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:15.015933 2017] [core:warn] [pid 6812:tid 252]
>   AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten --
>   Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:15.218945 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6812:tid 252]
>   AH01909: localhost:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID
>   which matches the server name
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:15.271948 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6812:tid
>   252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.21
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:15.271948 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6812:tid
>   252] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:15.271948 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6812:tid 252]
>   AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d
>   C:/xampp/apache'
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:15.274948 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6812:tid
>   252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5588
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:16.048993 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5588:tid 264]
>   AH01909: localhost:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID
>   which matches the server name
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:16.473017 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5588:tid 264]
>   AH01909: localhost:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID
>   which matches the server name
>
> [Fri May 19 16:19:16.542021 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5588:tid
>   264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.